# IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.3 Spring 4 servlet xml will not deploy under WEB-INF

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I have been stuck on this one for a while.  I have been trying to follow a Spring tutorial.  Below is my dispatcher servlet configuration in my web.xml

```
 <servlet>
        <servlet-name>crunchify</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>crunchify</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/welcome.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/welcome.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

I have crunchify-servlet.xml under WEB-INF.  I have not been able to get the application to run because Spring reports it cannot find the file under web-inf.  I have setup IntelliJ to deploy to the local tomcat as an exploded war, but it is omitting the xml for some reason.  Can anyone provide any guidance on what I may be missing in my IntelliJ setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the IntelliJ support and the resolution was to delete the .idea directory and the .iml file for the project.  Something got messed up in the config somewhere.  I then imported the project as a maven project and the ide rebuilt the .iml and .idea directory.  I had to reconfigure tomcat, but everything worked after taking these steps.